# Maximum Likelihood for constrained multivariate normal

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

Consider a sample of size $n$ from $\text{N}_p(k\mathbf{\mu_0}, \Sigma)$ where $k,\Sigma$ are the unknown parameters, and $\bf \mu_0$ is known. Now we have to find their MLE's.
I have solved this when $\Sigma$ is known, but when sigma is unknown, differentiating the log-likelihood w.r.t $k$ gives $\mathbf{\mu_0}^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(\overline{\mathbf{X}}-k\mathbf{\mu_0})=0$, but I can't solve it anyhow, and some help would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) What does "$N_p$" stand for? (2) Assuming it refers to the usual (not "constrained") multivariate normal family, as suggested in the title, why not emulate the standard maximum likelihood solution? As far as finding $\Sigma$ goes, you don't have to change anything.

Comment: @whuber Yes it means the multivariate normal distribution. But how can I solve for $k$? I don't see what you mean. Could you give some hints? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since you have solved it with $\Sigma$ known, you already know how to find $k$.  Now use the standard techniques for finding $\Sigma$.  Alternatively, emulate the standard techniques and include a set of Lagrange multipliers to handle the constraint on the mean.